# Simple upload ckeditor 5 cannot upload file: undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor 5 simple upload with laravel, however when I upload any image an alert with "localhost says Cannot upload file: undefined." I'm using the package below

https://github.com/shino47/ckeditor5-build-laravel-image

My js sample code looks like below:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cb = function() { return (new Date()).getTime() }
        ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
            simpleUpload: {
                uploadUrl: {
                    url: 'http://localhost/myendpoint'
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'token',
                    'x-header-cb': cb
                }
            }
          }).then(editor => {
            console.log('Editor created successfully!');
          }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err.stack);
         });
      });
```

Also, does anyone know a way of finding out the error?  There are no errors on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Your server endpoint must return a json like this :

```
{
   "uploaded": true,
   "url": "http://public/path/to/img"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD**: POST

Upload a file to the root (/) directory of the Files resource type.
Your file response should be like following

```
{
    "resourceType": "Files",
    "currentFolder": {
        "path": "/",
        "url": "/ckfinder/userfiles/files/",
        "acl": 255
    },
    "fileName": "fileName.jpg",
    "uploaded": 1
}
```

For more option visit : [LINK](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/commands.html#command_quick_upload)